# What determines amplitude resolution of oscilloscope FFT?

Tags: oscilloscope, fft

I am studying my oscilloscope's FFT measurement capability (Rigol DS1054Z. Links to [datasheet](https://www.rigol-uk.co.uk/jg/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/Rigol-DS1000Z-Oscilloscope-Datasheet.pdf) and [user guide](https://www.rigol-uk.co.uk/jg/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/Rigol-DS1000Z-UserGuide.pdf)), and do not understand what determines the amplitude resolution capability of the FFT measurement. It is an 8-bit oscilloscope, which is clearly part of the story. According to the user guide, the scope computes the FFT with 16,384 points.

An example of my experience with it is as follows: with a voltage gain setting of 500mV / division, and a sine wave input of 1V RMS (2.824 V p-p) at 1 kHz, I correctly measure an amplitude of 1 dBV (using flattop or Hanning window). If I slowly increase or decrease the amplitude of the sine wave from the function generator, there is no change until I get a discrete jump of 1 dBV, which happens when I have indeed increased the amplitude by about 1 dBV (which in this case is from 2.824 V p-p to 3.17 V p-p). I have the vertical scale of the FFT amplified as much as possible so that I can see the smallest change. Clearly I have hit the limits of the amplitude resolution of the scope.

I don't understand what determines this 1 dBV amplitude resolution. I can see noise at about 70 dB below the peak value, which gives me some sense of the dynamic range, but I don't see how to carry the reasoning through to determine a limit on the amplitude resolution and understand where the 1 dBV value comes from.

Comment: There's software between the input and FFT display, and software can be made to do anything. It's not unknown for displays to be 'filtered' or 'smoothed' so they don't show amplitude noise, and what better way to do that than trashing the resolution. Who knows what they could be doing. 1dB is a nice round number. With 8 bits going in, and 16k points, a straight FFT would give you far better resolution than you're seeing. I've got a 1054, but never used the FFT, I'll have to experiment some time.

Comment: I thought the 1054Z was 12-bit? But it probably doesn't reach that in terms of ENOB anyway.

Comment: @Hearth At the bottom of page 6 of the datasheet (link given in post) it lists the vertical resolution as 8 bits. Perhaps the 12-bit is a spec on some effective resolution extension using oversampling?